# Multidimensional Array view defined line

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

*I would like to see a single line with these elements.*

```
$ArrayDocs = array (
  0 => array ('titre' => 'aaa','ref' => 'aaa','date' => 'aaa','like' => aaa,'url' => 'aaa',),
  1 => array ('titre' => 'aaa1','ref' => 'aaa1','date' => 'aaa1','like' => aaa1,'url' => 'aaa1',)
  );
```

Example :

```
foreach($ArrayDocs AS $key => $doc)
    {
      echo $key.' '.$doc['titre'].' '.$doc['ref'].' ';

    }
```

Transform : **It does not work.**

```
 foreach($ArrayDocs[1] AS $key => $doc) // Example shows the line 1 of Table
    {
      echo $key.' '.$doc['titre'].' '.$doc['ref'].' ';

    }
```

Comment: what is ur expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you explicitly set the index in the parent array container to index `1` inside your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($ArrayDocs[1] AS $key => $doc) // Example shows the line 1 of Table
                 // ^
```

`print_r` result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [titre] => aaa
            [ref] => aaa
            [date] => aaa
            [like] => aaa
            [url] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array // when you set $ArrayDocs[1] inside foreach, you're already here
        (
            [titre] => aaa1
            [ref] => aaa1
            [date] => aaa1
            [like] => aaa1
            [url] => aaa1
        )

)
```

You don't need to have that index. So pointing into:

```
echo $key.' '.$doc['titre'].' '.$doc['ref'].' ';
             //   ^              //   ^ isn't needed
```

Just:

```
foreach($ArrayDocs[1] AS $key => $doc) // Example shows the line 1 of Table
{
    echo $key.' '.$doc . '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IKoNA7)

Comment: @LongEttinger yes, no need for extra index when its `$ArrayDocs[1]`, if its `foreach($ArrayDocs)` then you need it. glad this helped